# Trying to pass a value from a servlet to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to pass a value from a servlet java page to a jsp page, by using session.
Here is my code on the servlet page.

```
session.setAttribute ( "SPONSOR_ID", loginSponsorID ) ;
request.getRequestDispatcher("summary.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And here is the code on the jsp page

**This prints null value:** 
`<%=request.getAttribute("SPONSOR_Name")%>.`

I get errors when I try assigning the return value into a variable.

```
<c:set var=intMethod value"${'<%=request.getAttribute("SPONSOR_Name")%>'}"/>
```

Comment: you adding object to session key as `SPONSOR_ID` and in jsp you trying to retrieve by `SPONSOR_Name` so, you will always get `null`, and to access a variable you have JSTL, then why you using scriptlets again? you can retrieve by `${SPONSOR_ID}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo, you set value in session but trying to read from request. make these two calls in sync, use either session or request.

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this is the problem; You have setted SPONSOR_ID and trying to retrieve SPONSOR_Name.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SPONSOR_ID", loginSponsorID);
```

and in JSP

```
<%= session.getAttribute( "SPONSOR_ID" ) %>
```